# MySQL "Error loading password's vault file"

Tags: mysql

Something has gone very wrong and I'm getting nowhere on fixing this.

My machine booted, threw this error.  Showing the details comes up with "Key not valid for use in specified state".  The only English answers I have found point to a crypto cache in Windows, I renamed the cache directory so it would be rebuilt, no improvement.

I've completely uninstalled MySQL, the error comes up during the reinstall.  While there are a few databases on here there's no data of any value.

Comment: It is **NOT** MySQL message. MySQL [knows nothing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=201&p=1&q=%22vault+file%22) about it. I think it is the message produced by some anti-viral or anti-malware software.

Comment: @Akina I do agree it's probably coming from deeper in the system but MySQL is reporting it and is the only program having trouble.

Comment: @Akina Look at Oliver's answer--while the problem is deeper it was a MySQL thing.

Comment: Workbench is separate soft, not MySQL part. The fact they have the same author and may be installed and may work in complex alter nothing. Ever their documentation is separated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when you're changing your Windows password.
This message comes from MySQL Workbench.
To correct this issue, start MySQL Workbench and it will ask you if you want to clear the vault cache.
Then try to connect to your MySQL and click to save the password into the vault.

;)

Comment: Good old MySQL--cryptic errors for fairly routine things.